# Simple differential equation( introduction but need some basic explanation)

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I have a couple of questions before I dig deeper into my calculus book.

**First:**

I have learned that 
$\frac{d}{dx}\frac{x}{y}$=$\frac{y x'-x y'}{y^2}$

never really gotten a proper explanation for why suddenly when its differential equations it becomes as they have defined it in my book:

$$\mathrm {d}(\frac{x}{y})=\frac{y\mathrm dx-x\mathrm dy}{y^2}$$

I see algebraically that this is simply dividing by dx, but I HATE when I do not get a proper explanation for it.

**Second** is a more specific case from the start of the book:

$$x^2 y\mathrm {dy}-(x\mathrm dy-y\mathrm dx)=0$$

Now If I divide by $x^2$

$$y \mathrm dy-\mathrm{d}\left[\frac{x}{y}\right]=0$$,

Now I get what the point of doing this is: 
However it is the result that throws me off: 
$y^2/2-x/y=c$ But I am integrating both why is the constant positive. Is it simply just that c can take on a negative value, why does not the c's cancel out since I integrate both. I am not sure how to interpret this.

**Last question:**

$$\pm \frac{\mathrm {d}\left(x^2+y^2\right)}{2 \sqrt{x^2+y^2}}=\mathrm {dx}$$

Solving this produces

$$\pm \sqrt{x^2+y^2}=c+x$$,

However, I do not see how this makes it any easier unless $\mathrm {d}\left(x^2+y^2\right)=2x$, but if that's the case I am even more confused
since in this case y disappears as I am used to dealing with derivatives since nowhere it is stated that $y$ is a function of $x$. But that to me conflicts what happens in what i wrote under **First.**

Could someone please explain in detail why in the last instance: $\frac{\mathrm d\left(x^2+y^2\right)}{\mathrm dx}=2 y \frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx}+2 x$ is not the case, but simply $2x$. In one moment I can use the derivative as a fraction(FIRST) in the other (last question) I can not?

Comment: It is not necessary that both integrating constants are same, so you  can use two constants (say $C_1,C_2$) but we again can take $C_1-C_2=C$,that's why we use only 1 constant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lot of this is shorthand that is justified by defining "differentials" in a certain way. A truly rigorous treatment uses methods of differential geometry, for which a good book might be Weintraub's "Differential Forms".

The equivalence of $$\tag 1\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{M(x,y)}{N(x,y)}$$ and $$\tag 2-M(x,y)dx+N(x,y)dy=0$$ is by no means obvious.

$(1)$ should be clear: it's just a first order differential equation, presumably with an initial condition that is not shown.

For $(2)$ you need some calc III:

Suppose $f:\mathbb R^{2}\to \mathbb R$ is differentiable at $\vec x=(x,y)\in R^{2}$. Let $\vec h=(\Delta x, \Delta y)$

Then $$\tag 3\lim _{\vert \vec h\vert \to 0}\left | \frac{f(\vec x+\vec h)-f(\vec x)-\nabla f(\vec x)\cdot \vec h)}{\vec h} \right |=0$$ where $\nabla f(\vec x)=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(\vec x)\vec i+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(\vec x)\vec j$.

This formula just says that if $f$ is differentiable at $\vec x$ then the tangent plane

$$\tag 4z(\vec h)=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(\vec x)\Delta x+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(\vec x)\Delta y$$ is a good approximation to $f$ if you are near the fixed point $\vec x$.

Now, suppose $\nabla f$ is identically zero $\textit {in some neighborhood N of}$ $\vec x$. Then. $f$ is constant on $N$.

(I'll do the proof of this fact at the end).

So we have

$$\tag 5f(x,y)=C$$ for some constant $C$. from which one presumably can solve for $y$ (although this requires proof of course).

Set $\Delta x=dx;\Delta y=dy$. Then you get$$\tag 6z(\vec h)=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}dx+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}dy=0$$.

Now compare $(6)$ and $(2)$ and relate this to $(5)$. When you write $(2)$ you are implicitly assuming $(6)$ and therefore $(5)$. So now we have the meaning of $(2)$: we seek a function implicitly defined by $(5)$. Luckily, the method one uses to do this will also say whether such an $f$ exists.

Now for the proof of the claim. If $\nabla f$ vanishes on $N$, then $f$ is constant there:

A neighborhood $N$ of $\vec x$ is simply a disk, so if we pick $\vec a$ and $\vec b$ in $N$, then there is a line segment connecting $\vec a$ and $\vec b$ so we can take

$g:[0,1]\to \mathbb R^{2}$ defined by $t\mapsto t\vec b+(1-t)\vec a$ and then consider

$\varphi =f\circ g:[0,1]\to \mathbb R$.

We may now apply the ordinary MVT to write

$\varphi (1)-\varphi (0)=\varphi '(c)(1-0)$ for some $c\in (0,1)$. This is

$$\tag 1f(\vec b)-f(\vec a)=\varphi '(c)$$ But the chain rule says that

$\varphi '(c)=f'(g(c))\cdot g'(c)=\nabla f(g(c))\cdot (\vec b-\vec a)$. Now observe that $c\in (0,1)\Rightarrow g(c)\in N$ because the entire line segment from $\vec a$ to $\vec b$ is in $N$. But by assumption $\nabla f=0$ on $N$ so in fact, $\nabla f(g(c))=0\Rightarrow \varphi '(c)=0$ and now from $(1)$ we conclude that $f(\vec b)=f(\vec a)$. As $\vec a$ and $\vec b$ were arbitrary vectors in $N$, the claim follows.

Comment: Brilliant! What is the conditions for the neighborhood. I would guess there has to be a certain size?

Comment: Determining how large the neighborhood is is another issue. The point here is that there IS one. I will post on this shortly.

Comment: It is so brilliant! Thank you very much! So exciting!!!!

Answer (score 2):

"dy/dx" is NOT a fraction but is defined as the **limit** of a fraction, the "difference quotient".  A result of that is that the derivative can often be treated like a fraction.  For example, if y is a function of u and u is itself a function of x, then y can be considered a function of x and, by the "chain rule", dy/dx= (dy/du)(du/dx).  We **cannot** prove that by simply "canceling" the two "du" terms but we can prove it by going back before the limit, doing the canceling there and taking the limit again.

Since "dy/dx" can be **treated like** a fraction, a *notation* has been developed to emphasize that.  Given y= f(x) so that dy/dx= f'(x) we **define** the "differential", dy, to be equal to f'(x) dx where dx, quite simply, is left as an "undefined" term but treated its as an "infinitesimal" change in x.  That allows us to do things like change "dy/dx= f(x)" to "dy= f(x)dx" and then integrate both sides.

It is simply a notational device to remind us that we can do things that otherwise would not be so obvious.

Comment: Could you explain my last question as I am not able to see why this is the case?

Answer (score 2):

For your Last expression see:

Note that: $$\mathrm {d} f(x,y)=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}.\mathrm {dx}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}.\mathrm {dy}$$

$$\mathrm {d} \sqrt{x^2+y^2}=\mathrm {d}(x^2+y^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}\\
=\frac{1}{2}(x^2+y^2)^{\frac{-1}{2}}\cdot\mathrm {d}(x^2+y^2)\\
=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{(x^2+y^2)}}\cdot d(x^2+y^2)$$

So, $$\pm\int  \frac{d\left(x^2+y^2\right)}{2 \sqrt{x^2+y^2}}=\pm \int \mathrm {d} \sqrt{x^2+y^2}\\
=\pm \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$$

Also, $$\mathrm {d}(x^2+y^2)=2x\mathrm {dx}+2y\mathrm {dy}$$

so,$$\frac{\mathrm {d}(x^2+y^2)}{\mathrm {dx}}=2y\frac{\mathrm {dy}}{\mathrm {dx}}+2x$$

Comment: Do not see the simplification you have done ! Could you show me how you can include the denominator and then simplify?

Comment: The last one is 2y not 2x, as far as I know but its the simplification happening on your line number two that I do not get. Line to going from left hand side two right hand.

Comment: My problem is that I can take the derivative and solve, that is not the problem. But if I were not given the original function I am suppose to find the original myself. And Im not sure If I would be able to, I do not see how the integrating factor makes me realise what the original function is.

Comment: @ ALEXANDER: It is not easy to find integrating factor and making differential exact, there are some rules for finding integrating factor but they are not enough to make all given differential exact.There is no rule which provides us integrating factor at look of differential.

Answer (score 0):

if this is your equation $$x^2ydy-(xdy-ydx)=0$$ i would write $$x^2y\frac{dy}{dx}-x\frac{dy}{dx}+y=0$$ or $$x^2y(x)y'(x)-xy'(x)+y(x)=0$$

Comment: you need to correct the error in first line

Comment: y^2 should be x^2

Comment: is your equation correct now?

Comment: Yes, it is correct! Could you please explain what I am missing in the last question?